# Any fullpagejs code for a custom transitions when scrolling a sections?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition, fullpage.js

"I'm developing a fullpage website using fullpagejs. Everything works fine but I would like to customized the scroll transition just like this website scroll transition. https://www.hellomonday.com/ "

When you notice in hellomonday scroll animation, the origin section will slide slowly while the next section will slide fast. 
How can I achieve that custom transition?
I already have a hint in fullpagejs option "easingcss3" but still cannot achieve my goal.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bloop-fullpage').fullpage({
        navigation: false,
        slidesNavigation: false,
        loopHorizontal: false,
        scrollingSpeed: 800,
        scrollBar: false,
        autoScrolling: true,
        easingcss3: 'cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000)',
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the [Parallax extension for fullpage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/parallax.html).

There you'll see exactly the same "overlay" concept. 
Perhaps the animation is not exactly the same, but I'm pretty sure can achieve it by customizing the `easingcss3` option of fullPage.js, which defaults to `easingcss3: 'ease'`